# Minor Issue: Where is the better place to put User.objects.create_user in DRF?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Recently, I have reviewed my previous codes in Django thoroughly line by line. And I've got a minor issue.

I have a preference to put ORM method to VIEW, not serializer. For example, I would like to make `User.objects.create_user` into APIView class like below.

```
class SignUp(APIView):
def post(self, request):
    serializer = SignUpSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        User.objects.create_user(
            email=serializer.validated_data['email'],
            password=serializer.validated_data['password1'],
            first_name=serializer.validated_data['first_name'],
            last_name=serializer.validated_data['last_name'],
        )
    return Response(data=serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

However, I've found many people code like below overriding create method in serializer.

```
class SignUpSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
password1 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
password2 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('pk', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'first_name', 'last_name')

def validate(self, data):
    if data['password1'] != data['password2']:
        raise serializers.ValidationError('password should match')
    return data

def create(self, validated_data):
    return self.Meta.model.objects.create_user(
        email=validated_data['email'],
        password=validated_data['password2'],
        first_name=validated_data['first_name'],
        last_name=validated_data['last_name']
    )
```

I personally consider that serializer is more like data convertor, not reproducer.

I would appreciate that you are able to share your opinion about this minor issue :)

p.s I've said it minor issue because I am aware of this can be a matter of taste.

Comment: as you said view is the better option; but let's say you are require to use the same serializer in multiple cases; in that case if you need to keep create method universal you can create it within serializer but it's a rare case that you need to use same serializer for multiple functionalities

Comment: Thanks! That really makes sense.